# How to find out all palindromic numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

A [palindromic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) or numeral palindrome is a "symmetrical" number like 16461, that remains the same when its digits are reversed.

The term palindromic is derived from palindrome, which refers to a word like rotor that remains unchanged under reversal of its letters.

The first palindromic numbers (in decimal) are:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22,
33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101, 111,
121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181,
191, ...
```

How to find out all palindromic numbers below, say, 10000?

Comment: Not to rain on any parades, but why are these numbers interesting? A number that's palindromic in base 10 may not be palindromic in other bases. For that matter, is 1100 a palindrome when it's written as 001100?

Comment: I've added a less "brute-force" approach to my answer.

Comment: I believe this is a Project Euler quesion, try searching on that for more information

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Generating all palindromes up to a specific limit.

```
public static Set<Integer> allPalindromic(int limit) {

    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9 && i <= limit; i++)
        result.add(i);

    boolean cont = true;
    for (int i = 1; cont; i++) {
        StringBuffer rev = new StringBuffer("" + i).reverse();
        cont = false;
        for (String d : ",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split(",")) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt("" + i + d + rev);
            if (n <= limit) {
                cont = true;
                result.add(n);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

### Testing for palindromicity

#### Using Strings

```
public static boolean isPalindromic(String s, int i, int j) {
    return j - i < 1 || s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j) && isPalindromic(s,i+1,j-1);
}

public static boolean isPalindromic(int i) {
    String s = "" + i;
    return isPalindromic(s, 0, s.length() - 1);
}
```

#### Using integers

```
public static boolean isPalindromic(int i) {
    int len = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(i+1));
    for (int n = 0; n < len / 2; n++)
        if ((i / (int) Math.pow(10, n)) % 10 !=
            (i / (int) Math.pow(10, len - n - 1)) % 10)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Does your solution happen to miss those palindromes of the form (i + "" + rev)? For example (unless I'm misunderstanding how Java's string split works), would 11, 22, 33, be generated by this code?

Comment: @aioobe this line `for (String d : "0123456789".split(""))` will not produce the expected result in java8 .. split function doesn't adds a blank space in java8 at the beginning of the array

Answer (score 27):

Revert your reasoning. Not try to find these numbers but instead create them. 
You can simply take any number and mirror it (which is always even in length) and for that same number simply add 0..9 in between (for the numbers with odd length).

Comment: Moreover your method provide a very clear algorithm to compute the number of  palindromic numbers below a certain number. It could be possible to answer the question "How to find out all palindromic numbers below (say 10000)?" very very quickly.

Comment: How would you determine which numbers to generate when the length is equal to the length of the limit number?

Comment: @aioobe: depends how general you think the question should be. The limit is "below (say 10000)" -- if that means the limit can be any integer then it's fiddly, but if that means the limit can be any power of 10 it's trivial.

Comment: @aioobe Finding the offset isn't that hard either, simply reverse the steps of your desired limit. So you need to split in the logical parts which are for the example 10|0|00. With just a couple of checks you can determine your offset.

Comment: @M Platvoet, You mean finding the largest palindromic number below the given limit? I find it quite hard. If you see a simple solution, please share it with me. I've updated my answer to generate all palindromic numbers up to a given limit though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a brute force approach, that you loop through all the numbers and check whether they are palindrome or not. To check, reverse the number and compare. Complexity should be O(n log10(n)). [ Not that log10() matters, but for sake of completeness. ]

Other one is to, generate palindromes according to number of digits. Lets say you have to generate 5 digit palindromes, they are of the form ABCBA, so just loop through 0-9 and fill all the positions. Now, if you have generate palindromes below 10^4, then generate palindromes of 1,2,3 and 4 digits.

I wrote quick(and dirty) C++ codes to test the speed of both the algorithms (8 digit palindrome).
Brute force : [Ideone.](http://www.ideone.com/qV1z3) (3.4s)
Better algorithm : [Ideone.](http://www.ideone.com/asvTo) (0s)

I have removed print statements, because Ideone doesn't allow this large data in output.

On my computer the times are :

```
Brute force:
real    0m7.150s
user    0m7.052s
Better algorithm:
real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.012s
```

I know that you have mentioned language as Java, but i don't know Java and these codes simply show you the difference between the algorithms, and you can write your own Java code.

PS: I have tested my code for 8 digit palindromes with brute force, can't be sure if it produces wrong for above 8 digits, though the approach used is general. Also, i would have liked to give the links to code in comments, as correct approach is already mentioned, but i don't have required privileges.

Answer (score 2):

one approach is simply iterating over all numebrs, and checking each number: is it is a palyndrome or not, something like that:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(Integer x) {
        String s = x.toString();
        int len = s.length();
        for (int i = 0;i<len;i+=2) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(len-i-1)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 10000;
        for (Integer x = 0;x<N;x++) { 
            if (isPalindrome(x)) System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Brute force approach: Make a foreach loop from 1…10000 and test against the constraints. Even easier, convert the number to string, reverse it and compare it to the original value. This is inefficient and lame.

Better approach: Think about the patterns of a palindrome. Think about the different possibilities there are for palindromes, depending on the length of the number. Now provide a method that generates palindromes of the given length. (I will not do this, because it's obviously homework.)

Answer (score 1):

Loops similar to the one below can be used to print palindrome numbers:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                System.out.println("" + i + j + k + j + i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer. Please run and check the output.

Comment: The output of the program is `10001` `10101` `10201` and so on. It should be starting from `1` and till `10000`.

Comment: This loop is for 5 digit palindromes.. I specified in my answer that similar loops may be used for other sets depending upon need.

Comment: The ordering of the answer changes, you should mentions it clearly by words. Currently your answer is coming at the bottom of the page. No below answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these methods in C# which may be of some help. The main method builds a definitive list of all palindromic numbers up to the given number of digits. Its fast and commented throughout to help explain the processes I have used.

I've also included some support methods including a fast palindromic test and its worth pointing out that pow10[x] is an array of the powers of 10 to further improve speed.

```
                    lhs *= 10;
                    rhs /= 10;
                }
                palindrome = MathExt.Concat( lhs * 10, MathExt.ReverseDigits( rhs ) );      // Multiplying the lhs by 10 is equivalent to adding b == 0
                result.Add( palindrome );       // Add numbers of the form aaa + 0 + aaa

                lhs = a;
                for ( ulong b = 1; b != 10; b++ )
                {
                    rhs = a * 10 + b; // Adding b before we reverse guarantees that there is no trailing 0s
                    palindrome = MathExt.Concat( lhs, MathExt.ReverseDigits( rhs ) );       // Works except when b == 0
                    result.Add( palindrome );       // Add numbers of the form aaa + b + aaa
                }
                a++;
            }
            pow *= 10;        // Each pass of the outer loop add an extra digit to aaa
        } 
        return (result);
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///  Reverses the digits in a number returning it as a new number. Trailing '0's will be lost.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">The number to reverse.</param>
    /// <param name="radix">The radix or base of the number to reverse.</param>
    /// <returns>The reversed number.</returns>
    static public ulong ReverseDigits( ulong n, uint radix = 10 )
    {
        // Reverse the number
        ulong result = 0;
        do
        {
            // Extract the least significant digit using standard modular arithmetric
            result *= radix;
            result += n % radix;
            n /= radix;
        } while ( n != 0 );
        return (result);
    }


/// <summary>
    /// Concaternates the specified numbers 'a' and 'b' forming a new number 'ab'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>If a = 1234 and b = 5678 then Concat(a,b) = 12345678.</example>
    /// <param name="a">The first number.</param>
    /// <param name="b">The second number.</param>
    /// <returns>The concaternated number 'ab'.</returns>
    public static ulong Concat( this ulong a, ulong b )
    {
        // Concaternate the two numbers by shifting 'a' to the left by the number of digits in 'b' and then adding 'b'
        return (a * pow10[NumberOfDigits( b )] + b);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Evaluate whether the passed integer is a palindrome in base 10 or not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">Integer to test.</param>
    /// <returns>True - Palindrome, False - Non palindrome.</returns>
    static public bool IsPalindrome( this ulong n )
    {
        uint divisor = NumberOfDigits( n ) - 1;
        do
        {
            // Extract the most and least significant digits of (n)
            ulong msd = n / pow10[divisor];
            ulong lsd = n % 10;

            // Check they match!
            if ( msd != lsd )
                return (false);

            // Remove the msd and lsd from (n) and test the next most and least significant digits.
            n -= msd * pow10[divisor];  // Remove msd
            n /= 10;                    // Remove lsd
            divisor -= 2;               // Number has reduced in size by 2 digits 
        } while ( n != 0 );
        return (true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Queue
import copy

def printPalindromesTillK(K):
    q = Queue.Queue(K);
    for i in range(0, 10):
        q.put(str(i));
        q.put(str(i) + str(i));
    while(not q.empty()):
        elem = q.get();
        print  elem;
        for i in range(1, 10):
            item = str(i) + elem + str(i);
            if int(item) <= K:
               q.put(item); 

print printPalindromesTillK(10000);
```

Comment: The question is about Java. This answer does not look like Java at all.