# Double string comparison using recursion

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble with a question from my programming II class and have hit a brick wall, was wondering if someone could help?

The question asks for a user to input a string, the program to reverse the input string and then to compare the reverse to the original, this must be done recursively.

So far I have:

```
public class question1 
{
public static void main(String args[])  
{

String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a sentence to determine if it is a palindrome.");
String backwardsinput = Reverse(input);
System.out.println(backwardsinput);
boolean Palindrome = PalindromeCheck(backwardsinput, input);

    if (Palindrome == true)

        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is a palindrome!");
        }

    if (Palindrome == false)

        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That is not a palindrome"); 
        }

}

public static String Reverse (String input)
{
    if (input.length() <= 1)
    return input;

    else
    {
        char x = input.charAt(input.length()-1);               
        return x+Reverse(input.substring(0,input.length()-1));
    }

}



public static boolean PalindromeCheck (String backwardsinput, String input)
{

     if(input.length() == 0 || input.length() == 1)
            return true;

        if(backwardsinput.charAt(0) == input.charAt(input.length()-1))
            return PalindromeCheck(backwardsinput.substring(1, backwardsinput.length()-1), input.substring(1, input.length()-1));

        else
        return false;

       }    
}
```

My problem is, it tells me everything is a palindrome, I've looked at it over and over and can't figure out why!

Comment: Maybe they should *first* teach you how to *format* your code, then move on to other topics.

Comment: If you could point out what I'm doing wrong or point me towards some resources on the matter, I'd appreciate it. I just want to learn and do the best job I can afterall.

Comment: @Bohemian: Not the worst formatting I've seen - it's only the top bit that needs some work! AND Eogcloud, I like your code dispite the formatting and errors! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing the work twice (sort of).

```
if(backwardsinput.charAt(0) == input.charAt(input.length()-1))
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

should be

```
if (backwardsinput.charAt(0) == input.charAt(0))
                                             ^
```

You almost got it :-)

---

Also, another way of expressing

```
if (cond)
    return something;
else
    return false;
```

is

```
return cond && something;
```

thus your last lines could be written as

```
return backwardsinput.charAt(0) == input.charAt(0) &&
       palindromeCheck(backwardsinput.substring(1, backwardsinput.length() - 1),
                                input.substring(1, input.length() - 1));
```

---

**Related question / answer:**

- [How to find out all palindromic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401289/how-to-find-out-all-palindromic-numbers)

Comment: The last bit is helpful, I didn't know you could structure return statements like so, thanks!

Comment: Thanks aiobe, I wasn't aware about that way of returning but now that I think about it, it doesn't make sense because it's just like a single-line if else statement!

Comment: Which doesn't make sense? My proposal?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(backwardsinput.charAt(0) == input.charAt(input.length()-1))
```

This doesn't work. You want `backwardsinput.charAt(0) == input.charAt(0)`. because you reversed it.

When I debug something like this, I tend to pull apart all my compound statements, so

```
if(backwardsinput.charAt(0) == input.charAt(input.length()-1))
```

would become

```
char bc = backwardinput.charAt(0);
char ic = input.charAt(input.length()-1);
System.println(bc);
System.println(ic);
if (bc == ic) {
```

We all make dumb mistakes when we try to put too much in one expression, so these are good places to start looking for logic errors.

Comment: That logical breakdown is an awesome idea, great way of finding mistakes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are reversing the string and then checking the string matchs this reversed. i.e. it tests that the String was reversed correctly.

When you can do is not reverse the string and then only check a String matches itself (ratehr than its reverse) backwards.

Comment: That would be the ideal situation! unfortunately for me, the question specifically states we must reverse it and recursively compare the original with the reverse :(

Comment: You can reserve it and compare the first character with the first character to compare strings.