# Generate all Palindromic numbers in a given number system?

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to generate all palindromic numbers for a given number base (which should be able to be of size up to 10,000), in a given range. I need a efficient way to do it.

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6401324/5821790), which is related to base 10 directly. I'm trying to adapt it to work for "all" bases:

```
public static Set<String> allPalindromic(long limit, int base, char[] list) {

    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();

    for (long i = 0; i <= base-1 && i <= limit; i++) {
        result.add(convert(i, base, list));
    } 

    boolean cont = true;
    for (long i = 1; cont; i++) {
        StringBuffer rev = new StringBuffer("" + convert(i, base, list)).reverse();
        cont = false;
        for (char d : list) {   
                String n = "" + convert(i, base, list) + d + rev;
                if (convertBack(n, base, list) <= limit) {
                    cont = true;
                    result.add(n);
                }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

`convert()` method converts a number to a string representation of that number in a given base using a list of chars for digits.

`convertBack()` converts back the string representation of a number to base 10.

When testing my method for base 10, it leaves out two-digit palindromes and then the next ones it leaves out are 1001,1111,1221... and so on.

I'm not sure why.

Here are the [conversion methods](https://pastebin.com/TjQxNtYi) if needed.

---

**Turns out, this gets slower with my other code because of constant conversions since I need the all numbers in order and in decimal. I'll just stick to iterating over every integer and converting it to every base and then checking if its a palindrome.**

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` has an overload with `base` parameter to convert a string of any base to integer,so does `Integer.toString`, you don't have to write conversion methods by yourself

Comment: @niceman [Max radix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX)= 36: I cannot convert to bases over 36 If I use that. If the value is under Min radix or over Max radix, value 10 is used instead.

Comment: hmmm agreed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but if you are only missing even length palindromes, then most probably there is something wrong with your list. Most probably you have forgot to add an empty entry in list as to generate 1001, it should be like num(10) + empty("") + rev(01).

Comment: That's the case, I see now that. But char[] can't have an empty character. I replaced my char[] with String[] to include "", but I need to fix my convertBack and convert methods now.

Comment: @Vepir If you don't want to change much, then you can simply handle this case explicitly. Just do str+revStr, before looping through your list

Answer (score 1):

There is no so many appropriate chars for digits in all possible bases (like `0xDEADBEEF` for hex, and I suppose that `convert` has some limit like 36), so forget about exotic digits, and use simple lists or arrays like `[8888, 123, 5583]` for digits in 10000-base.

Then convert limit into need base, store it. 
Now generate symmetric arrays of odd and even length like
`[175, 2, 175]` or `[13, 221, 221, 13]`. If length is the same as limit length, compare array values and reject too high numbers.

You can also use limit array as starting and generate only palindromes with lesser values.

Comment: Unicode (utf16) char can hold value up to 65535. But I am not sure that output with such chars will be readable

Comment: My proposal is to avoid using conversion (except for text output)